# discord.py[voice] installed with pip but not detecting in vs code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, discord.py

I had installed discord.py for use within vs code before installing vs code. I have now installed the [voice] part of discord.py and it is not being recognized by vs code. I just get the error "No name 'voice' in module 'discord'" and "Unable to import 'discord.voice'". I had installed discord.py before installing vs code but installed discord.py[voice] after installing vs code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import `discord.voice`.

If you installed discord.py with pip from pypi (`pip install discord.py`), then you have installed async version of library (not rewrite as mentioned in tags).

[Check examples of voice usage](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/playlist.py), and [library documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)